# How to add glib header file in C?

Tags: c, gcc, header, glib

I am getting a compilation error saying:

```
In file included from glib.c:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:10: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
   30 | #include <glib/galloca.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

when I try including glib to my C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

int main () {
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

I am trying to include the glib header file to my C file but I keep getting complilation error.

I tried compiling with the following commands:

```
gcc glib.c
```

This gives me the above error

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs glib` glib.c
```

This gives me the below error

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--libs’; did you mean ‘--libs=’?
```

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs=glib` glib.c
```

This also gives me an error,

```
cc1: warning: command-line option ‘-flibs=glib`’ is valid for Modula-2 but not for C
In file included from glib.c:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:10: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
   30 | #include <glib/galloca.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried using the full path

```
#include </usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h>
```

yet it gives me the same compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the command `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` on its own, you will see that it only lists the libraries to link with. It give you the *linker* flags, not the compiler flags needed to compile your program.

To get the compiler flags you need to use the `--cflags` option:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -Wall -Wextra glib.c -o glib `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

Note that I separate the compiler and linker flags. That's because libraries needs to be listed last on the command line.

Also note that I added some flags to enable more warnings, which is generally a good idea (and you should really treat and warning you get as an error that *must* be properly fixed).

---

It also seems to be an issue with using backtick commands, and the error is typical when using e.g. Fish instead of Bash.

There are two major issues working against you here:

- First Fish uses parenthes instead of backticks for subcommands
- Then Fish assumes that arguments are separated by newline not space (see https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#my-command-pkg-config-gives-its-output-as-a-single-long-string)

To solve this we need to use e.g. this instead:

```
gcc \
  (pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 | string split -n " ") \
  -Wall -Wextra glib.c -o glib \
  (pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 | string split -n " ")
```

It might be simpler to use a simple Makefile or other similar built-tools to help you.

Comment: I still get the same error:


gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--cflags’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--libs’; did you mean ‘--libs=’?

Comment: My gcc version is 11.3.0 if that helps in anyway

Comment: @amogh Let me guess: You're not using Bash as the shell, but perhaps Fish? Then you can't use back-tick commands as "usual". Updated my answer to include a solution for Fish.

Comment: Yeah, I am using fish but I didn't think the shell would be a problem. Ironically I am using glib for my own shell implementation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @amogh Then you'll probably want to split your project into multiple files, so if you don't know how to use makefiles or meta-build tools like CMake then this is a good time to learn! :) Good luck!